# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sin^2(x^2)$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sin^2(x^2)$$
I assume the limit doesn't exist but how do I show it?

Do I use sequences somehow?

Comment: Look at the function at $x=\sqrt{2n\pi}$ and $\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi/2}$.

Comment: the limit dont exist.

Answer (score 2):

As $x$ marches on toward infinity, it is reasonable to guess that the function $\sin^2(x^2)$ visits both 0 and 1 infinitely often. Can you construct an infinite sequence of values such that $\sin^2(x^2)$ evaluates to 0 for each term in the sequence? What about a similar sequence for which it evaluates to 1?

Comment: if i take a_n = root(2npi) and b_n = root((2n+1)pi/2), then both of these sequences tend to infinity as n tends to infinity, but f(a_n) tends to 0 as n tends to infinity, and f(b_n) tends to 1 as n tends to infinity, so because they are not equal, the limit does not exist. Does this work?

Comment: @bws It sounds great, but I would add that $f(a_n)$ does not just tend toward 0, it is *equal* to 0 for all $n$. Similarly for $f(b_n)$.

Comment: oh, yes, my bad, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function $\sin^2 x$ never approaches a value as $x\to\infty$, it oscillates.

Comment: A real function taking on the value $\;-1\;$ is highly unlikely.

Comment: @TravisJ Why the strange edit?

Comment: @Did, the $-1$ was my mistake (as I was thinking $\sin(x)$ not $\sin^{2}(x)$.  I removed the "never approaches a value" since that is false as $\lim_{x\to a}\sin^{2}(x)=\sin^{2}(a)$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Did, oscillates seems fine (as long as the $a$ is $\infty$)... as $x\to \infty$ the value of $\sin^{2}(x)$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$.  Unless you feel like that asserts that it only takes on the values $0$ and $1$?

Answer (score 0):

If a function $f$ admits a limit, say $L$, as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ then for any sequence $(x_n)$ which tends to $\infty$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges to $L$ too. However, if you take the two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ given by André Nicolas above, you will find that the two sequences $(f(x_n))$ and $(f(y_n))$ do not have the same limit. It follows that the limit do not exists, our function $f$ do not have a limit as tends to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

One can even show the set of values of $\sin^2 n^2$ ($n$ is an integer) is *dense* in the interval $[0,1]$ (not trivial!).

Comment: Actually more or less trivial, by continuity of the sine function.

Comment: @Did: Actually, I was thinking of a nearby problem: when $x$ is  a integer.

Comment: Actually you might want to modify your post.

Comment: @Did:  done (pun intended :o)).